# Functional Components eslint 'date' is missing in props validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I used protoTypes,but eslint throw  `'date' is missing in props validation`

```
function SpreadTitle(props) {
  return (
    <div >
      <div>{props.date}</div>
      <div>latestUpdateTime: {props.latestUpdateTime}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

SpreadTitle.protoTypes = {
  date: React.PropTypes.string,
  latestUpdateTime: React.PropTypes.string,
}
SpreadTitle.defaultProps = {
  date: '',
  latestUpdateTime: ''
}
```

I meet this error only in Functional Components,it works but eslint throw warning
Spent 2 hours trying to fix this, Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: In your example it says `SpreadTitle.protoTypes`. Should this not be `propTypes`?

Comment: it should be `propTypes` instead of `protoTypes`.

Comment: thanks Niekert and  Mayank,Your help is greatly appreciated.I wonder if should use code hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chang "protoTypes" to "propTypes"

```
SpreadTitle.propTypes = {
  date: React.PropTypes.string,
  latestUpdateTime: React.PropTypes.string,
}
```

Comment: Muuuch obliged!